# Silverlight: How to receive notification of a change in an inherited DependencyProperty

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties

I have a control which inherits from (you guessed it) Control.
I want to receive a notification whenever the `FontSize` or `Style` properties are changed.  In WPF, I would do that by calling `DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata()`.  Of course, useful things like that have no place in Silverlight.  So, how might one receive those kinds of notifications?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think here is a better way. Still need to see the pros and Cons.

```
 /// Listen for change of the dependency property
    public void RegisterForNotification(string propertyName, FrameworkElement element, PropertyChangedCallback callback)
    {

        //Bind to a depedency property
        Binding b = new Binding(propertyName) { Source = element };
        var prop = System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ListenAttached"+propertyName,
            typeof(object),
            typeof(UserControl),
            new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(callback));

        element.SetBinding(prop, b);
    }
```

And now, you can call RegisterForNotification to register for a change notification of a property of an element, like .

```
RegisterForNotification("Text", this.txtMain,(d,e)=>MessageBox.Show("Text changed"));
RegisterForNotification("Value", this.sliderMain, (d, e) => MessageBox.Show("Value changed"));
```

See my post here on the same http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2009/12/silverlight-listening-to-dependency.html

Using Silverlight 4.0 beta.

Comment: I like that this is a nicer way of wrapping up that ugly binding, but that is an awfully heavy way to get property change notifications.

Comment: As long as we need to do it entirely from the code, I guess we don't have another option till we get the DependencyPropertyDescriptor in Silverlight from MS

Comment: I've also used this approach, unfortunately it leaks memory. In my experience it will hold a reference to what ever element you use it with, which will in turn hold on to other objects. The culprit appears to be the callback which will retain a reference to your view for the life of your application.

Comment: It works (+1!) but as Ian said its not optimal. As a workaround I've moved the attached property (in my case called `ListenAttachedIsEnabledProperty` to the class I want to override and added the following two lines in the constructor `var b = new Binding("IsEnabled") { Source = this }; SetBinding(ListenAttachedIsEnabledProperty, b);`

Comment: it will throw when calling RegisterForNotification for multiple textboxes probably because you can't create multiple DependencyProperties with the same Name.

Answer (score 6):

It's a rather  disgusting hack, but you could use a two-way binding to simulate this.

i.e. have something like:

```
public class FontSizeListener {
    public double FontSize {
        get { return fontSize; }
        set { fontSize = value; OnFontSizeChanged (this, EventArgs.Empty); }
    }

    public event EventHandler FontSizeChanged;

    void OnFontSizeChanged (object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (FontSizeChanged != null) FontSizeChanged (sender, e);
    }
}
```

then create the binding like:

```
<Canvas>
  <Canvas.Resources>
     <FontSizeListener x:Key="listener" />
  </Canvas.Resources>

  <MyControlSubclass FontSize="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource listener}, Path=FontSize}" />
</Canvas>
```

then hook up to the listener's event in your control subclass.

Comment: When the MyControlSubclass FontSize property change, the binding will be clear so it seems it doesn't work? not?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot externally listen to dependency property changed notifications.

You can access the Dependency Property Metadata with the following line of code:

```
PropertyMetadata metaData = Control.ActualHeightProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(Control));
```

However, the only public member that is exposed is "DefaultValue".

There are a multitude of ways to do this in WPF. But they are currently not supported by Silverlight 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I see is to listen to the LayoutUpdated event - yes,  I know it is called a lot. Note however that in some cases it won't be called even though FontSize or Style has changed.

Answer (score -3):

This is what I always use (haven't tested it on SL though, just on WPF):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method registers a callback on a dependency object to be called
    /// when the value of the DP changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner">The owning object.</param>
    /// <param name="property">The DependencyProperty to watch.</param>
    /// <param name="handler">The action to call out when the DP changes.</param>
    public static void RegisterDepPropCallback(object owner, DependencyProperty property, EventHandler handler)
    {
        // FIXME: We could implement this as an extension, but let's not get
        // too Ruby-like
        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(property, owner.GetType());
        dpd.AddValueChanged(owner, handler);
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure DependencyPropertyDescrtiptors are mythical beasts in Silverlight, unfortunately.

Comment: DependencyPropertyDescriptor is not supported by Silverlight 2 or 3