# Custom Control: How to Call Method When Inherited Dependency Property Changes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, uwp

I'm writing a custom control that inherits ItemsControl.  I need to call a method whenever certain properties change.  For my own dependency properties I can call this in the setter no problem, but for inherited ones like ItemsSource I don't know how to do this and I'd like to learn how without overriding the whole thing.

When searching for this I saw [mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834929/silverlight-how-to-receive-notification-of-a-change-in-an-inherited-dependencyp/1835068) that this could be done with OverrideMetadata in WPF at least (my project is UWP).  I see how OverrideMetadata is used to change the default value, but I don't see how it can be used as a property changed notification.

Comment: Can someone clue me in as to why this is a bad question so I don't get more reputation loss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a new method in UWP called `RegisterPropertyChangedCallback` designed just for this. For example, the following is how I remove the default entrance transition in an extended `GridView` control.

```
// Remove the default entrance transition if existed.
RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(ItemContainerTransitionsProperty, (s, e) =>
{
    var entranceThemeTransition = ItemContainerTransitions.OfType<EntranceThemeTransition>().SingleOrDefault();
    if (entranceThemeTransition != null)
    {
        ItemContainerTransitions.Remove(entranceThemeTransition);
    }
})
```

You can un-register using `UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback`.

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject).

Comment: I'm just overriding OnItrmsChanged which I was oblivious to before mm8 pointed it out, but this is clearly proper solution for any other property changes.

Answer (score 0):

For the `ItemsSource` property you could just override the `OnItemsSourceChanged` method but for any other dependency property you could use a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`:

```
public class MyItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    public MyItemsControl()
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ItemsControl));
        if (dpd != null)
        {
            dpd.AddValueChanged(this, OnMyItemsSourceChange);
        }

    }

    private void OnMyItemsSourceChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

That goes for WPF. In a UWP app you should be able to use @Thomas Levesque's `DependencyPropertyWatcher` class: https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2013/04/21/detecting-dependency-property-changes-in-winrt/

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about OnItemsChanged, that's working fine.  I'll give the Thomas Levesque class a try if I need it.

Comment: IMHO the native approach is neater (and more performant?) than the watcher's binding approach.